# Can we create each boost logger instance for each class object?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I have using boost log for past three months. I am using boost logger as static in inside the class.

BoostLogger.h:

```
class CBoostLogger
{
private: 
  SharedPtr< SinkFileBackend > backend; 
  ...
public: 
  static src::wseverity_logger_mt< logging::trivial::severity_level > slg;
...
}
```

BoostLogger.cpp:

```
#include "BoostLogger.h"
////////////////////////////////////
//Global Declarations
////////////////////////////////////
src::wseverity_logger_mt< logging::trivial::severity_level > CBoostLogger::slg;
```

But I want to create individual logger for individual class object.
  Is it possible to create?
  Give your suggestions?

Regards,
  
Arun

Answer (score 1):

Several sources say that Boost logger can have multiple instances. You can read about this at [this link](http://www.torjo.com/log2/doc/html/getting_started.html) or [this link](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.log).

IMO I would use a single logger object and use specific messages to tell me from where the log entry originated, formated as follows: (file), (line of code), (method) log message;

E.g.: Main.cpp 25 main() : Warning, unable to open file.

Comment: Thanks. Assume that I am going to create I am having a class. In class, I create source::logger lg;  as public. And in class constructor, I am creating file using add_file_log. Is it possible to write in individual files using different class objects.

Comment: I used to write a single log file, then if really necessary I would parse the log file to extract the information I need, or I would use the search options from Notepad++ to filter out the results.